# React Native - React-native link error while linking instabug-reactnative

Tags: ruby, react-native, instabug

Here's the packge I am using for bug reporting (I am following the install instructions from [here](https://github.com/Instabug/instabug-reactnative)). But when I run `react-native link instabug-reactnative` it gives me the following error.

I followed some forums but none seemed to help. I guess the error is regarding ruby installation. Any idea What's going on here? Is it trying to link the files for ios and failing? Do I need to even run link command for android

In the installation guide 2 point is the following

```
2.) Install Ruby. (You can skip this step if you're building for Android only)
```

As per the instructions, I skipped this step beacause I am building for android only.

[image]